# Listen through iPhone microphone jack but play through speaker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio

I'd like my iOS app to listen via the headset microphone but play audio through the speaker on the iPhone. Is this possible? Imagine a loudspeaker type app...

Comment: You may not have access to the APIs that set the controls for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to accomplish this in very convoluted ways. But this requires you to have the latest SDK, i mean truly "the latest SDK" ;)

so if you are part of the ios developers program go and have a look for yourself. All you need to know is to customise your hardware audio routes. but it does not work on all the possible scenarios, only for certain hardware combinations. anyway go and have a look there is even a WWDC 2012 lecture on that. (Session 505)

Comment: AudioRoutes overriding has been around for a while I think, not just since iOS 6.

Comment: True, but to be honest I never managed to make it work beyond using external peripherals. i.e. usb devices through cameraConnection Kit. So with that hardware I was able to choose which input and what output providing it was external. Prior iOS6, It was not possible to push audio both to headset and speakers for example. Or to use the device microphone when the headset microphone was present. That was what I meant.